# React typescript - Type must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a demo here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-shopping-cart-ssofgc?file=Shop.tsx

Sorry this isn't the best question but

My demo is a simple shopping cart using React and Typescript.

Products can be added and removed from a cart.

My demo in stackblitz works but I have an error using the same code in my app.

In my app I get an error in the removeFromCart

I get the error here

```
const removeFromCart = (
    e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLInputElement, MouseEvent>,
    item: IProduct
  ) => {
    let cartCopy = [...cart]; // Error here - Type 'IProduct' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
    cartCopy = cartCopy.filter(cartItem => cartItem.id !== item.id);
    setCart(cartCopy);
  };
```

The error is

```
Type 'IProduct' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
```

Can anyone explain this error or how to fix it.

Comment: what is the cart type and where does `cart` come from? it doesn't appear to be an argument of your `removeFromCart` function

Comment: I see now (in your stackblitz link) that `cart` comes from `const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's weird you get the error where you say you are, seeing as you aren't using `item` on that line... I would think that your `cart` type would need to be "array like", ie. include `[Symbol.iterator]()` as part of it. You can read more about [Symbol.iterator on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator).

EDIT: I see now (in your stackblitz link) that `cart` comes from `const [cart, setCart] = useState([]);`, so it's definitely an array, so that shouldn't be an issue. Seems to me like there is something up with either your editor or your local project configuration...

Maybe you could try and be more explicit about your variable types. For instance, `items` and `cart` both appear to be `IProduct[]`, so you could change them be written like:

```
  const [cart, setCart] = useState<IProduct[]>([]);

  const items: IProduct[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "Product One",
      price: 12
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "Product Two",
      price: 45
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "Product Three",
      price: 23
    }
  ];
```

Comment: other than maybe being a little more explicit, I don't really see anything wrong with your code or your use of types. the only other thing I might suggest is that you define your types (or in this case interface) outside of `<Shop />`

Answer (score 1):

It is likely due to `lib` option in `tsconfig.json`. I had updated to some newer packages (Redux 7, React 16+) and noticed my config was woefully out-of-date.

### Before:

**tsconfig.json**

```
"target": "es2015",
"lib": [ "dom", "es5", "es2015.symbol", "es2015.core", "es2015.promise" ]
```

This config was throwing the error when using `React.useState`.

### After:

**tsconfig.json**

```
"target": "es2015",
"lib": [ "dom", "es2015" ]
```

Specifically, adding `es2015.iterable` will be enough for this specific error but there was no reason in my case not to add `es2015`.